# How to turn off Hotmail (Windows account) on Lumia 930?

Tags: outlook

On my Lumia 930, Battery Saver shows that my Hotmail account (Windows account), which I have never used, uses as much battery as the email account I do use. Why is this happening and can I turn off the Hotmail account? I have it set to check daily, which is the least frequent rate possible.

Comment: Is this question about Windows Phone 8 or Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't turn it off. That's the default account on your phone which is useful for downloading apps and games from store.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why Hotmail is using so much power when it is checking just once a day and I don't use it for email?

Comment: Are your mobile is on Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 10 software?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to sync email from that account, you can turn off the email sync entirely.

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Then **Accounts**
3. Select your Microsoft account.
4. Tap **Change mailbox sync settings**
5. Uncheck Sync e-mail.

Depending on your OS version, you'll have an option something like "Change mailbox sync settings" (this is the screen where you can control how often it syncs, too). Underneath the options for sync frequency and server name and so on, there will be a header something like "Sync options" with checkboxes (or similar toggle controls, depending on version) for Email (and possibly other things). Uncheck the Email control (and any others you see, if you're sure you don't want them).